# Splitting string into chunks of 2 C#

Tags: c#, string

I have the following string:

```
            string input ="this is a testx";
```

I need to remove the spaces and then split the input into chunks of two, so I can process every two letters individually:

th is is at es tx

I tried to remove the spaces with:

```
input=input.Remove(input.IndexOf(' '),1);
```

Then I couldn't do much with the splitting...

Comment: What code have you tried? Are you getting an exception or incorrect results?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> output = input
    .Replace(" ", string.Empty)
    .Select((ch, i) => new{ch, grp = i/2})
    .GroupBy(x => x.grp)
    .Select(g => string.Concat(g.Select(x => x.ch)));
```

or more sensibly :)

```
input = input.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
IEnumerable<string> output = 
   Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length / 2).Select(x => input.Substring(x * 2, 2));
```

you can use the output as follows:

```
foreach(var item in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: That moment, when 2 lines `for` is replaced with 5 lines LINQ :-)

Comment: I'm relatively new to programming and I never used LINQ before :( 
I didn't understand the whole code

Comment: @zerkms I experienced a bit of a self-wtf moment when I saw your comment! Hopefully my second approach makes amends :-)

Comment: @spender: yep, actually it employs the plain-old-`for` implementation logic in a really nice way :-)

Comment: @user3571294 I'll cover the second approach because the first is... novel. `Enumerable.Range(0,length)` creates a sequence of ints from 0 to length-1 (where in this case it's half the length of the string). We then (for every int in the sequence), Select a portion of the string.

Comment: I know it will sound silly but how can I use the result of this query?

Comment: In depth? It is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) that takes a sequence of items as a parameter. Then, for every item in the sequence, it calls the second parameter, defined by the [lambda expression](http://www.codefoster.com/linqlambda/) `x => input.Substring(x * 2, 2)` supplying each item in the sequence as parameter `x` to the lambda. The return value of the lambda is projected into a new sequence and returned by `Select`. If it still doesn't make sense, take a read of the links in this comment.

Comment: @WaelT : I added a little.